# How to inherit generic case class to reuse its properties?

Tags: scala, generics, case-class

How to properly implement this in Scala?

```
case class WithPagingJson[T](meta: PagingMetaJson, objects: Array[T])

case class CandidatesListJson extends WithPagingJson[CandidateJson]
case class OpeningsListJson extends WithPagingJson[OpeningJson]
```

As you see, these classes are models for JSON data received from various APIs.
They all have same basic structure with two top-level properties for paging info and for array of requested objects.

Compiler tells me case to case inheritance is prohibited.
What is a proper Scala way of doing this?

Comment: Don't ever extend a `case class`. Yes, Scala allows you to extend a `case class` but you really should not.

Comment: My goal is to not type same definition 10 times. It's not that my goal is to extend case class. I use uPickle library to work with JSON, it expects me to use case classes for models. All models have same structure - top level paging info and top level array of objects. So it was natural to think I can just define all models that way. I see now I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `CandidatesJson` really doesn't add anything to `WithPagingJson`, it can be a type alias:

```
type CandidatesJson = WithPagingJson[CandidateJson]
```

Otherwise, does `WithPagingJson` really need to be a case class? If you make it `abstract` and all its subtypes `case class`es, then you effectively still get all the equality, hash code, etc. benefits.

> Would you mind showing the code for inheriting from abstract class?

```scala
abstract class WithPagingJson[T](val meta: PagingMetaJson, val objects: Array[T])

case class CandidatesJson(override val meta: PagingMetaJson, override val objects: Array[CandidateJson]) extends WithPagingJson[CandidateJson](meta, objects)
```

> it seems I will have to exactly repeat whole parameters list for case class anyways? I actually was hoping to avoid exactly that.

If they are the same, yes, but they don't have to be. Maybe you want to make the base type a trait instead

```scala
trait class WithPagingJson[T] {
  val meta: PagingMetaJson
  val objects: Array[T]
}

case class CandidatesJson(meta: PagingMetaJson, objects: Array[CandidateJson]) extends WithPagingJson[CandidateJson]
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey! Would you mind showing the code for inheriting from abstract class? I am new to scala but it seems I will have to exactly repeat whole parameters list for case class anyways? I actually was hoping to avoid exactly that.